# how declare two variables in for init in GoLang?

Tags: go

when i write:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func Sqrt(x float64) float64 {
    var ret float64

    for z := 1.0, n := 0;n < 10;n++ {
        ret = z - (z*z - x) / 2*z
    }
    return ret
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Sqrt(2))
}
```

syntax error: z := 1.0, n used as value.
and bring

> z := 1.0

out of the for block below

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func Sqrt(x float64) float64 {
    var ret float64
    z := 1.0
    for n := 0;n < 10;n++ {
        ret = z - (z*z - x) / 2*z
    }
    return ret
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Sqrt(2))
}
```

it's ok so how can i define two variables in init of the for block?

Comment: yes, the synax is somehow different from other language which i used before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [For clause](https://golang.org/ref/spec#ForClause) has an [Init Statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#InitStmt) which is a [Simple Statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#SimpleStmt), including only one [Assigment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignment)

So in your case, you cannot declare multiple variable with different type/values. You could use a tuple assignment though

```
for z, n := 1.0, 0; n < 10; n++ {
```

([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DUS1W6_8cB))